# Disable PowerShell output message wrap after 80 characters

Tags: command-line, powershell

By default, PowerShell wraps output messages after 80 characters (see example #1).

**Example #1:**

```
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'HKLM' does not exi
st.
At /Users/me/here-is-a-very-long-path-that-will-ultimately-be-wrapped-after-80-
characters/myScript.ps1:34 char:19
```

**Example #2**:

```
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'HKLM' does not exi st.
At /Users/me/here-is-a-very-long-path-that-will-ultimately-be-wrapped-after-80- characters/myScript.ps1:34 char:19
```

Is there a command-line switch or configuration setting that allows to override this (like in example #2?) I'm looking for a solution that works without adding additional code to existing script files, e.g. a flag or a global setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the console host who breaks the lines to fit on the screen. Either change the settings in the Posh console or inside a script you may redirect broken output to a file - then there is no line break.
You may also change the window and buffer size from inside a script. See:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI
```

But the buffer.width has first to be increased

A different way is to maximize the host window, [here is nice function](https://gist.github.com/jakeballard/11240204) but lines 29+30 need to be stripped from leading spaces.